# Mac OS X Mountain Lion doesn't recognize devices plugged into USB serial ports

Tags: macos, serial-port, arduino, osx-mountain-lion, ftdi

Since I migrated to Mountain Lion, the USB serial ports to which the Arduino is connected are no longer visible to the Arduino app, menu (Tools -> Serial Port). It just shows the interfaces via Bluetooth.

The serial ports that appear on my Mac:

[image: Mac Arduino serial ports menu]

I've tried installing [the VCP drivers](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) and reinstalled the Arduino. I tried to run an older version of Arduino IDE and have even reinstalled the Mac OS X from scratch.

None of that solved the problem... I really need to communicate with my Arduino, how I can fix this?

Comment: Hi Hugo,  You would get a lot better feedback from the Arduino forums on this issue since it is not really a programming question.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be on-topic here. It may be appropriate either at [SU] or [Electronics.SE].

Comment: Hm, just to make sure: on my Mountain Lion system the usb entries appeared only when a valid device was plugged in. Probably you have to try different board types or (physically) different boards.

Comment: I disagree that the question is not on topic. It pertains to the Arduino - and is not some general EE topic.

Comment: @Hugo Demiglio  it works on mountain lion  u have to install this driver and the ports will be back [link](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm)

Comment: @WM. Thank you! You just saved me a lot of headaches!